# Odd Multiple of 3 in prolog

Tags: prolog

I need someone can help to how to do Odd Multiple of 3 in Prolog

> Define a predicate `oddMultOf3/1` that determines whether an integer is
>   an odd multiple of 3. A user should be able to enter the predicate
>   with an integer, e.g. `oddMultOf3(42)` and evaluate to either true or
>   false. If the given parameter is not an integer, your predicate should
>   display the message “ERROR: The given parameter is not an integer”.

they asked me to do this

```
oddMultOf3(171).
true.
oddMultOf3(100).
false.
oddMultOf3(12).
false.
oddMultOf3(4.2).
ERROR: The given parameter is not an integer
oddMultOf3(-9).
true.
```

but I keep receiving error everytime when I try.

this my code

> oddMultOf3(N) :- Y is N mod 3, Y=0.

Comment: How is that an odd multiple of three?

Comment: `Y is N mod 3, Y = 0` established a multiple of 3. Now how do you suppose you might establish that `N` is odd? Just add that condition.

Comment: @lurker Right, so add a condition to check whether N mod 2 is 0 then? Since for example 30 is a multiple of 3 which is even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know an *odd multiple of three* means that `N` is an integer, `N/3` is an integer, and `N/3` is *odd* (as in *not even*). So that means that if perform modulo 6, it has to be 3.

Actually there are two cases here:

- `N` is not an integer, in that case we show the error, and perhaps we should `fail` as well. So:

  ```
  oddMultOf3(N) :- 
      \+ integer(N),
      !,
      print("ERROR: The given parameter is not an integer"),
      fail.
  ```
- Otherwise we check if `N mod 6` is equal to `3`:

  ```
  oddMultOf3(N) :-
      3 is N mod 6.
  ```

Or putting it together:

```
oddMultOf3(N) :- 
    \+ integer(N),
    !,
    print("ERROR: The given parameter is not an integer"),
    fail.
oddMultOf3(N) :-
    3 is N mod 6.
```

We then obtain in `swi`:

```
?- oddMultOf3(171).
true.

?- oddMultOf3(100).
false.

?- oddMultOf3(12).
false.

?- oddMultOf3(4.2).
"ERROR: The given parameter is not an integer"
false.

?- oddMultOf3(-9).
true.
```

Comment: thanks a lot but when I tired your code its give me wrong result for example : oddMultOf3(171). have to be true but in your code gave me false

Comment: @user8286060: fixed.